# C realloc (dynamic arrays) - Access Violation

Tags: c, dynamic, visual-studio-2015, access-violation

Starting out with dynamic arrays in C. I am getting an access violation when in the insertArray function (either in the realloc line or when trying to store the element (char) in the array.

Can't seem to work around it or get to the bottom of it. Thanks

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

Array elements;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = (char *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, char element) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (char *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char));
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void popArray(Array *a) {
    a->used--;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) {
    free(a->array);
    a->array = NULL;
    a->used = a->size = 0;
}

char vars[15];

int main() {
    initArray(&elements, 2);
    printf("Enter 15 character String: ");
    scanf_s("%s", vars, 15);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        insertArray(&elements, vars[i]);
    }
    freeArray(&elements);
}
```

Comment: Is `popArray()` used in the true failing code?

Comment: in this particular code it is not used as I isolated this part of the code from a larger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is caused by the missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to understand why you should not cast the return value of `malloc`.